# Do we need temporarily lower rep privilege levels?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

As recently [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24324038#24324038), we have a relatively small number of users with sufficient reputation to process the review queues for close votes and low quality posts, and a smaller number still who are actively engaged in the review queues. This means that items are stuck in the review queues for far longer than is healthy.

**In the past (although very rarely), the rep levels for such privileges have been temporarily modified for some new sites that are not yet ready for the standard public beta rep levels. For example, [this happened with Quant.SE](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/why-are-privilege-levels-at-quant-se-not-the-standard-public-beta-levels) last year.**

**Is this something that our site would benefit from, to ensure we can review quickly while we continue to build our scope?**

---

Currently, [voting to close requires 500 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared). This means we have 17 [users who can work the close vote queue](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985?page=1&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top). We have 19 [users who have previously worked the close vote queue](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats), of whom 6 active users (non-trivial rep) have rep below 500 and are no longer able to do so since we reached public beta. So it seems likely that there are at least a few people who would be interested in reviewing if they had the privilege, in addition to any others who never had the chance to review when the queue was sparse early on. This backs up the expressed desire in the chat transcript linked to above.

Comment: The rep level for voting to reopen is also 500, so lowering the limit would allow both more close votes and more reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

We need one or two more active participants for this to work. At the moment there are 4 such persons, that atleast have similar scoping goals.

This makes it hard for us to get anything closed. Four people can not close, period. Since we do not have community mods they can not close at all.

Another thing is: There might not be consensus as to what to close. I can see some users wanting to keep some questions open.

Comment: Yes I agree, in addition to needing 5 to close, we also need more than 5 so that closing does not require 100% consensus. Ideally I'd like to see at least 10 with close and reopen privileges *and* actively using them (so probably double that number with the privilege to allow for people who don't use it).

Answer (score 2):

*My opinion as a user, rather than as a moderator:*

---

We now have moderators, who can close questions that are obviously off topic.

We also now have 22 users with over 500 reputation, able to work the close and reopen queues, and several more who are fast approaching 500.

I think we have managed to reach a point where we can keep the site on track without the need for an exceptional measure like reducing privilege reputation levels.